# Stack 2D array vertically

Tags: python, numpy

I want to stack the first n columns of a 2D array vertically. My realization is in the following:
`np.vstack(input_seq[:,:n].flatten().tolist())`

I am wondering if stacking 1D array directly would be faster? `np.vstack(input_seq[:,:n].flatten())`

Or are there any faster approaches to stack lists? Asking since I'm gonna repeat this process millions of times.

Any hint would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try *profiling your code*? Asking which approach would be faster is *an empirical question*

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm asking in the hope of finding a more in-depth explanation about stacking arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Just reshape your array:

```
new = input_seq[:, :n].reshape(-1)
```

Since you're indexing, the reshaped array is already a copy, so you can manipulate it without changing the original array (a reshaped array points to the same data otherwise).

Note that this method makes `new` one dimensional, while your methods make it two dimensional. If you need your new array to be two dimensional, just reshape it with an extra dimension of 1:

```
new = input_seq[:, :n].reshape(-1, 1)
```

Comment: How is your first expression different from `flatten()` or `ravel()`?

Comment: "Since you're indexing, the reshaped array is already a copy" I don't believe so, the first expression is a slice, which should create a view, unless I am misunderstanding `n`